# Notification with fireDate fires straight away

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I have the below notification that is being set up to fire at 9pm either on that day (if its currently before 9PM) or 9PM the next day (if its past 9PM already).

Everything seems to look right however it always just displays the notification right away no matter the  current time.

```
let hour = 21
                let minute = 0

                let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: .gregorian)!;

                var dateFire = Date()

                // if today's date is passed, use tomorrow
                var fireComponents = calendar.components( [NSCalendar.Unit.day, NSCalendar.Unit.month, NSCalendar.Unit.year, NSCalendar.Unit.hour, NSCalendar.Unit.minute], from:dateFire)

                if (fireComponents.hour! > hour
                    || (fireComponents.hour == hour && fireComponents.minute! >= minute) ) {

                    dateFire = dateFire.addingTimeInterval(86400)  // Use tomorrow's date
                    fireComponents = calendar.components( [NSCalendar.Unit.day, NSCalendar.Unit.month, NSCalendar.Unit.year, NSCalendar.Unit.hour, NSCalendar.Unit.minute], from:dateFire);
                }

                // set up the time
                fireComponents.hour = hour
                fireComponents.minute = minute

                // schedule local notification
                dateFire = calendar.date(from: fireComponents)!

                print(dateFire)

                let notification = UILocalNotification()
                notification.alertBody = "TEST"
                notification.soundName = "Default"
                notification.fireDate = dateFire

                UIApplication.shared.presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `UIApplication.shared.presentLocalNotificationNow`, which does exactly what it says, it presents the notification right as the method is called.

If you want to schedule a local notification, you need to first import `UserNotifications` (with iOS 10+)

```
import UserNotifications
```

Then you can schedule a notification like so:

```
func registerLocalNotification(date: Date) {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    content.categoryIdentifier = "YOUR_IDENTIFIER"
    content.title = "YOUR_TITLE"
    content.body = "NOTIFICATION_BODY"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    // Use date components to create a trigger time
    let triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day,.hour,.minute,.second,], from: date)
    print("Register: \(triggerDate)")
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: false)
    // Instantiate the notification request
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "SOME_IDENTIFIER", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    // Schedule the notification.
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.add(request) { (error) in
        // Handle error if necessary 
        print("Notification Added")
    }

}
```

You also need to make sure you've properly registered for notifications using the new `UserNotifications` in your `AppDelegate`

```
import UserNotifications

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in

        if granted {
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }

    }

    return true
}
```